# Getting error when reading element in array

Tags: reactjs, json, react-bootstrap

I'm making the E-commerce app, I have a client side using react & react-bootstrap to implement the UI. In the UI, I have component called ProductDetailScreen that fetch the json object of product from backend using axios.get('api/products/:category/:id'). Everything is good, I got the specific product when I have URL based on category and id, in the product object I have the  key name "image" with value of array stores the links of image from images folder ( image: ['images/earphones/ep1.png', '/images/earphones/ep1card.png'] ). But the problem is appear when I try to read one of these element from that array to render UI (product.image[1]). Error is Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '1'). Can anybody help me to fix that problem. I check on network tab of Chrome Dev Tool and respone status code is 200 OK that's mean I successfully fetch product from api

[image: I tried to log my object that I fetch from backend]

[image: and then I tried to log the element of image array in the product object, I got TypeError]

The result is Uncaught TypeError when I try to read element in the specific index of array

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import { Col,Container,ListGroup,Row,Card,Image,Button } from 
"react-bootstrap";
import Rating from "../Components/Rating.js";
import {useParams} from "react-router-dom";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

function ProductScreen() {
   let {category, id} = useParams();

   const [product, setProduct] = useState({});

   useEffect(() => {
      const fetchProduct = async () => {
      const res = await 
      axios.get(`/api/products/${category}/${id}/`);
      setProduct(res.data);
   };

   fetchProduct();
}, []);

console.log(product.image[1]);

return (
<Container className="mt-4">
  <Link className="btn btn-light mb-3" to="/">
    Go back
  </Link>

  <Row className="d-flex">
    {/* <Col md={6}>
      <Card style={{border: "none"}}>
        <Card.Header className="d-flex" style={{border: "none"}}>
          <Card.Img
            variant="top"
            style={{maxWidth: "100%", width: "400px", height: "400px"}}
            className="m-auto thumbnail-image"
            src={product.image[1]}
          />
        </Card.Header>
      </Card>
    </Col> */}

    <Col md={3}>
      <ListGroup variant="flush">
        <ListGroup.Item>
          <h2>{product.name}</h2>
        </ListGroup.Item>
        <ListGroup.Item>
          <Rating
            ratingStats={product.rating}
            reviewStats={product.numReviews}
            ratingColor={"#FDCC0D"}
          />
        </ListGroup.Item>
        <ListGroup.Item>{`Price: $${product.price}`}</ListGroup.Item>
        {/* <ListGroup.Item>{`Descriptions: ${product.description[0] + product.description[1]}`}</ListGroup.Item> */}
      </ListGroup>
    </Col>

    <Col>
      <ListGroup>
        <ListGroup.Item>
          <Row>
            <Col>Price:</Col>
            <Col>${product.price}</Col>
          </Row>
        </ListGroup.Item>

        <ListGroup.Item>
          <Row>
            <Col>Status:</Col>
            <Col>
              {product.countInStock > 0 ? "In-stock" : "Out-of-stock"}
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </ListGroup.Item>

        <ListGroup.Item>
          <Row>
            <Button variant="dark">ADD TO CART</Button>
          </Row>
        </ListGroup.Item>
      </ListGroup>
    </Col>
  </Row>
</Container>
 );
 }

 export default ProductScreen;
```

Comment: Hey @Tai before your question getting negative voting because of not sharing code. Please share code by editing the post or post your code on https://codesandbox.io/ and share the link in the post. Thanks

Comment: I’d assume the fetch hasn’t completed yet.

Comment: @DaveNewton But when I check with Postman, I can say the fetch is complete because the response shows me the object of the product based on categories and id params, the link below is the postman image [link](https://ibb.co/RDGYvC6)

Comment: `const [product, setProduct] = useState({})` so for *some* renders `product === {}` and `produce.image === undefined`

Comment: @Thomas so I need to add the dependencies on useEffect right?

Comment: Thanks for your answer y'all, I found the way to fix it, I set another useState for image, when ever useeffect called, it will set image for productImg state

Comment: Your console.log runs immediately; the product isn’t set until the fetch completes.